# Any way to center tooltip by text not by the th element?

Tags: html, css, text, html-table, tooltip

I have the following:

```css
[tooltip] {
  position: relative;
}

/* Arrow */
[tooltip]:before {
  width: 16px;
  height: 6px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: 1px;
  top: calc(100% - 10px);
  opacity: 1;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #00204e;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
  -o-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
  transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
  pointer-events: none;
}


/* Text */

[tooltip]:after {
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: 11px;
  top: calc(100% - 10px);
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-shadow: none;
  background: #00204e;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(tooltip);
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: normal;
  width: max-content;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
  line-height: normal;
  max-width: 150px;
  text-align: left;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
  -o-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
  transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 10;
}

[tooltip]:hover:before,
[tooltip]:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  top: calc(100% + 0px);
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 10;
}

th {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <th class="dijitButtonContents" id="saveButton" tooltip="Save as draft">This a heading</th>
</table>
```

My requirement is the tooltip on hover should appear as the center of **text** itself within the table heading but not the actual table heading.

I know that I can decrease the table heading width or make it auto to fit the text but this won't be the solution as the requirements are different. I need to focus on the text length itself.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You would need to wrap the text in a span and put the tooltip on that:

```css
[tooltip] {
  position: relative;
}


/* Arrow */

[tooltip]:before {
  width: 16px;
  height: 6px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: 1px;
  top: calc(100% - 10px);
  opacity: 1;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #00204e;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
  -o-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
  transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
  pointer-events: none;
}


/* Text */

[tooltip]:after {
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: 11px;
  top: calc(100% - 10px);
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-shadow: none;
  background: #00204e;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(tooltip);
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: normal;
  width: max-content;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
  line-height: normal;
  max-width: 150px;
  text-align: left;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
  -o-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
  transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 10;
}

th:hover [tooltip]:before,
th:hover [tooltip]:after,
[tooltip]:hover:before,
[tooltip]:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  top: calc(100% + 0px);
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 10;
}

th {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <th class="dijitButtonContents" id="saveButton"><span tooltip="Save as draft">This a heading</span></th>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there any to get tooltip populated on hover of `th` also?

Comment: see edit above - you just need to add hover css for the th

Comment: I cant add span or wrap the text inside span because its a system that is generating the code. I can only apply css.

Comment: Then you can't do what you want